# hibernate: using criteria to access objects within objects

Tags: hibernate, detachedcriteria

I am using criteria to get a list of notifications that contains users that are active. The problem is that i get the following error:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: user.active of: com.company.Notification
```

Other then checking that the user is active i need to check that the notification is of a type that i want. Here is my code:

```
session.createCriteria("com.company.Notification")
    .add(Restrictions.or(Restrictions.eq("type", "email"), 
    .add(Restrictions.eq("user.active", true)).list();
```

Notification has a field `User user` which in turn has a field `Boolean active`

i am looking at this page: https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?t=948576&highlight=subproperty

but i am still not groking how to create a criteria that accesses something in the parent object and in child object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this:

```
session.createCriteria("com.company.Notification")
    .add(Restrictions.or(Restrictions.eq("type", "email")
    .createCriteria("user") // this creates the join on the user table...
    .add(Restrictions.eq("active", true)).list();
```

hope that helped...